# How do I redirect in nodejs express with different request body

Tags: node.js, express, request

i am making the webside , here is some of my code

in app.ts

```
import * as express from 'express';
import knex from './init/knex';

// Router
import indexRouter from './routers/index-router';

// Service
import gameService from './service/game-service';

const app = express();
var server = app.listen(8080, () => {
   console.log('listen to 8080');
})

app.use('/', new indexRouter(new gameService(knex)).router());
```

in index-router.ts

```
import * as express from 'express';

export default class indexRouter {
   private gameService: any;
   constructor(gameService: any) {
      this.gameService = gameService;
   }

   router() {
      let router = express.Router();
      router.get("/", this.get.bind(this));
      router.post("/test", this.test.bind(this));
      return router;
   }

   test(req: any, res: any) {
      // console.log("indexRouter get()");
      console.log(req.body);
      res.render("gameboard", { pin: "1", username: "1", player: 1 });
   }

   get(req: any, res: any, next:any) {
      req.body = {3:"3"};
      // something i want to do here
   }
}
```

When user link to "http://localhost:8080/" and "get" method is called
How can i change:

1. the url from "http://localhost:8080/" to "http://localhost:8080/test"
2. call "test" method with the new request body

I have spent a lot of time google how to do i but i can't find the best way to do the above two things.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like:

```
   get(req: any, res: any, next:any) {
      test(req.body);
      res.redirect('/test');
   }
```

?

Comment: i want to redirect to the new link "/test" with new request body

Comment: but res.redirect now allow to do that